# White background flashing when switching screens - React-Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm migrating a RN project version 4 to 5.

When switching screens there was an issue with a white background flashing in.
In v4 this was solved by setting `cardStyle: { backgroundColor: material.containerBgColor }` in the `StackNavigation` options.

However in v5 I'm unable to fix it with the same approach:

`<Stack.Navigator cardStyle={{ backgroundColor: material.containerBgColor }} ...>`

White flash has come back. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Update:
The structure of the navigation may be important:

```
const AppTabNavigator = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ScreenD" component={ScreenD} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ScreenE" component={ScreenE} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ScreenF" component={ScreenF} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
)
...
  <Stack.Navigator
    ...
    cardStyle={{ backgroundColor: material.containerBgColor }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={AppTabNavigator} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ScreenC" component={ScreenC} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Going from ScreenD to ScreenE does the flashing issue. I'm not sure about the other screens as they don't make any network request / async stuff.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I have the same issue

Comment: If I remember correctly, the solution was somewhere in the native level. You can set the app bgcolor in a `plist` file for iOS and `gradle` file in Android. Good luck!

Comment: I managed to fix the glitch by removing all the LayoutAnimation pieces of code. Thanks!

Comment: @andreicovaciu For me LayoutAnimation is also causing this, however just removing all LayoutAnimation code seems like a bad solution imo.

Answer (score 64):

I faced the same issue and dived into an investigation. It seems that the detachment of the screens causes it. I found a few approaches. You can choose one according to your needs. They are the following:

1. You can specify a view wrapper of the navigator with the same background color as the screens one like:

   ```
   <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#YOUR_SCREEN_COLOR' }}>
     // It could be your NavigationContainer or your StackNavigator depends on your goals 
     <Navigator /> 
   </View>
   ```
2. You can also specify your screen mode to be `modal` in the stack view config this prevents the screens from being detached like:

   ```
   <StackNavigator.Navigator mode="modal">
     {/*.... Your stack screens ... */}
   </StackNavigator.Navigator>
   ```
3. You can add your custom overlay in `screenOptions` by using the `cardOverlay` prop:

   ```
   cardOverlay: () => (
     <View
       style={{
       flex: 1,
       backgroundColor: '#YOUR_COLOR',
     }}
   />)
   ```

   Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#cardoverlay
4. You can use the `cardStyleInterpolator`:

   > This allows you to customize the animation transitions when navigating from screen to screen.

   Here are the snippets from the original documentation:

   > ```
   > const forFade = ({ current, closing }) => ({
   >   cardStyle: {
   >     opacity: current.progress,
   >   },
   > });
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > <Stack.Screen
   >   name="Profile"
   >   component={Profile}
   >   options={{ cardStyleInterpolator: forFade }}
   > />
   > ```
   >
   > Stack Navigator exposes various options to configure the transition animation when a screen is added or removed.

   Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animation-related-options

Comment: Option one worked for me. I wrapped the NavigationContainer inside a view.

Comment: chiming in here, none of these worked for me, react navigator v5, the solution below by marcelo monteiro worked for me

Comment: @fullStackChris I don't think it is correct to say that none of the described issues above don't work for you, since the solution which is described by Marcelo Monteiro is based on option 4 (CardStyleInterpolator) - `"4. You can use the cardStyleInterpolator:"`

Comment: its Useful just wrap stacknavigator inside view and add bgcolor to it.

Answer (score 49):

Fixed it by using the DarkTheme for the Navigation Container

```js
import { NavigationContainer, DarkTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';

return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={DarkTheme}>
       {children}
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: This was the only way I could find to make this work in React Navigation 6. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely the best answer, without having to rely on workarounds.

Comment: Note that this requires upgrading to React Navigation v6 and won't work in v5

Comment: Actually I can confirm it worked for me on v5.

Comment: This helps a lot, even when using a modal, there is still a white flicker at the top of the screen if you don't set the theme to dark.

Answer (score 23):

I am also using StackNavigator in v5, but none of the answers worked for me. That's how I solved the issue:

```
const navigatorOptions = {
  headerShown: false,
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
  cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current: { progress } }) => ({
    cardStyle: {
      opacity: progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 1],
      }),
    },
    overlayStyle: {
      opacity: progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, 0.5],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
      }),
    },
  }),
}
 
...

<AppStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={navigatorOptions}
  mode="modal"
>
...
```

I've found the solution here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#transparent-modals

Comment: Adding onto this, if you want to have this fade animation but retain the vertical fly in, you can replace the opacity card style interpolation with: `cardStyle: { transform: [{ translateY: progress.interpolate({ inputRange: [0, 1], outputRange: [window.height, 0] }), }], },`

Answer (score 13):

An easy fix to this problem that worked for me is to set the `sceneContainerStyle` in the Tab Navigator like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator sceneContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
...//your screens here
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: This answer is working fine with any `Tab` navigator. Almost all other answers concerned the `Stack` navigator.

Comment: This also worked well for a `Drawer` Navigator

Comment: Fantastic, worked for me on React Navigation v6 on a tab navigator!

Comment: Fixed my problem!

Answer (score 8):

```
const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.appStyle}>
     <Navigation />
  </View>
);
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appStyle: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#000" }
});
```

Comment: For me this didn't work

Comment: For me it did work, and it was the only solution in React Navigation v6

Answer (score 7):

Using `react-native-navigation:^6.0.0`, I tested everything here but actually the only things that work is to set a theme on the NavigationContainer

```js
theme={{
  colors: {
    background: 'black', 
  },
}}
```

Comment: Doesn't this just make it flash black instead of white?

Comment: Well, It's not a flash anymore then.

Answer (score 5):

I used the solution provided by @jul

```
<SafeAreaProvider style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>
```

Small difference is that our `SafeAreaProvider` wraps `NavigationContainer` at a much higher level.

```
<SafeAreaProvider style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>
   ...
   <NavigationContainer />
   ...
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

Serves as a default background color without using native modules to set the root background color

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was due to the default styles of a SafeAreaProvider inside a NavigationContainer. Setting

```
<SafeAreaProvider style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}>
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.18",

```
<Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          presentation: 'transparentModal', <--- Add this props
        }}>
       <Stack screens here/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

I fixed my issue and hope it will help

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the issue by disabling the sceneAnimationEnabled of the Tab Navigator.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  sceneAnimationEnabled={false}>
  {...}
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: not working to me

Answer (score 3):

Just use `'transparentModal'`

```
<Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      presentation: 'transparentModal',
    }}>
   <Stack screens here/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: This has unwanted side effects: the previous screens are not removed from stack, but still rendered. So all the screens behave like modal, probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by setting `lazy={false}` in the `<Tabs.Navigator>` component:

```
<Tabs.Navigator
    lazy={false}
>
```

Comment: Hi, you're real angel. It worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem doing this in the `app.json` file: (but i had the same background color on every page)

```js
"expo": {
    "backgroundColor": "#YOUR_COLOR",
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, I have a way to handle the colors on the other screens.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me.

```
<NavigationContainer
        theme={{dark: true, colors: {...DarkTheme.colors, background: "YOUR_COLOR"}}}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was the only one that helped me. It seems the flash comes from the NavigationContainer theme background.

Answer (score 1):

`cardStyle` is an option on the screen, not the navigator.

```js
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ cardStyle: backgroundColor: material.containerBgColor }}>
  {/* ... */}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Or

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={AppTabNavigator}
    options={{ cardStyle: backgroundColor: material.containerBgColor }}
  />
  {/* ... */}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/stack-navigator.html#cardstyle

Probably a better way is to use the theming system to pass your colors rather than specifying it for every navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/themes.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification however the issue hasn't gone away :/

Comment: Which package are you using for tab navigation?

Comment: "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.0-alpha.39",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0-alpha.29",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0-alpha.63",

Answer (score 1):

The problem with me was that I had `enableScreens()` was enabled in my App.tsx.

You have 2 options:

- Remove the `enableScreens()` call
- add `detachPreviousScreen: false` to your `screenOptions` of your navigator and `enableScreens(true)` to your App.tsx

Answer (score 1):

for expo you can change `backgroundColor` in `App.json` file to `#000000`.

The background color for your app, behind any of your React views. This is also known as the root view background color.

Answer (score 1):

Put the  outside your NavigationContainer with flex: 1 and backgroundColor with the color you like

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this code: you can also put `cardStyleInterpolator` in the `options` property of each `<Screen>`

```js
const notAnimation = () => ({});

screenOptions={{ cardStyleInterpolator: notAnimation }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-native-navigation:^4.4.4`, the issue is resolved by disabling the animation.

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {...<YOUR_CONFIG>},
  {
   ...
   defaultNavigationOptions: {animationEnabled: false}, // Add this line
  },
);
```

No need to worry about `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will work -
Just wrap the navigator inside a view and give it a background color and don't forget to set flex

Answer (score 0):

For me adding cardStyle was enough to fix it.

```
const navigatorOptions = {
  ...
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color merely "hides" the problem. For me, the problem arose when I switched to `react-native-navigation:^6.0.0`, but it only happened on screens where I was using `LayoutAnimation.configureNext()` in a `useEffect` callback (used to trigger effects when a state changes).

What completely solved the problem for me was to put the `LayoutAnimation.configureNext()` in the callback function that triggers the state change, instead of passively listening to it with `useEffect` (because it seemed that the `useEffect` trigger on render + the `LayoutAnimation` caused the flash).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by wrapping navigationContainer inside the SafeAreaProvider which is imported from react-native-safe-area-context and give background color to it.

```
<SafeAreaProvider style={{backgroundColor: Colors?.backgroundColor}}>
    <NavigationContainer>
        <StackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

try it if this works fine, then give upvote and tick the answer.
Thanks